# How do I inject more than one environment variable into a Playbook task?

Tags: ansible, environment-variables

I have an Ansible playbook that I did not write myself. In it, I've identified the relevant task to my issue. This task runs as a another user, and within the docker container it appears this user doesn't have the correct environment variables for the task to run successfully.

```
- name: Run enmasse -> /opt (02)
  become: true
  become_user: "zato"
  environment: 
    SOME_TEST_VAR: some-value
  shell: |
    /usr/bin/find /opt/hot-deploy/enmasse -type f \( -name "*.yml" ! -name "default.yml" \) -exec ~/current/bin/zato enmasse {{ zato_env_path }}/server1 --import --input '{}' --replace-odb-objects --verbose \;
```

I've experimented by adding the environment directive to the task and setting arbitrary environment variables. These values seem to pass through and be available to the task correctly. However, for the actual work, I have a long list of environment variables I wish to pass through to the task, a list that will probably constantly grow.

If all of my environment variables are given some prefix, is there a simple one-liner that might suffice to pull all of those in? I've found some tutorials and documents that show how environment variables can be read from within Ansible, like so:

```
"{{ lookup('env','HOME') }}"
```

But if there is a more sophisticated way other than listing each var in that list, I can't figure out how to search for it.

Comment: try setting `environment: "{{ ansible_env }}"`

Comment: @P.... This works. I had to do env > /tmp/env.txt to see it, but it's working. The bad news is that somehow that's causing the command itself to fail. Thinking it's some special character in a var value.

Comment: Glad its working, can you add the error you are facing now?

Answer (score 1):

Question:

> *I have a long list of environment variables I wish to pass through to the task, a list that will probably constantly grow.*

According the documentation [setting the remote environment in a task](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_environment.html#setting-the-remote-environment-in-a-task)

> *You can store environment settings for re-use in multiple playbooks by defining them in a `group_vars` file.*

as well

> *re-use environment settings by defining them as variables in your play and accessing them in a task as you would access any stored Ansible variable.*

```yaml
environment: "{{ env_variables }}"
```